# How could I give a k8s role permissions on Service Accounts

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to create a role that will have permissions to create service accounts in Kubernetes (and only that), but I'm getting permission denied errors, I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

This is my role definition

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: create-SA
rules:
 - apiGroups: [""]
   resources: ["serviceaccount"]
   verbs: ["*"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the resource needs to be serviceaccounts, and not in singular.